# Windows applet to log on/off Gmail?

Tags: windows, gmail

Gmail's anti-spam filter is much better than my web hoster's, so I used a Gmail account just to download e-mails from my web hoster's POP accounts, massage them, and send them to my ISP's account from which I download the virtually spam-free remaining e-mails.

It worked fine for several months, but I found out today that this account was disabled. I didn't go through the legalese, so I assume the user is required to actually log on to Gmail every so often or see their account disabled.

Before I write one myself, I was wondering if someone knew of a Windows applet that would either install as a Windows service or sit in the icon bar and just log on/off regularly so as to keep Gmail happy?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Gmail Notifier](http://toolbar.google.com/gmail-helper/notifier_windows.html)

Comment: Thanks Graeme. By any chance, do you or someone know whether Gmail notifier reallys logs on, so that this account won't also be disabled one day?

Comment: Well it does have to log on in order to check if you have new email. I can't say whether using it exclusively counts towards the type of activity Google takes into account when deciding whether to keep your account active or not.

Comment: Thanks. I'll see if this new account survives longer :-)

Comment: You might try asking your question in this thread: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/gmail/thread?tid=56abbf1fbd0629c9&hl=en